# Why assignment in for loop can change global variable while it cannot in function?

Tags: julia

The following returns 1, indicating a `local x` is created.

```
x = 1
bar() = (x = 2)
bar() # 2
x # 1
```

This returns 5, indicating both x refer to the global one.

```
x = 1
for i = 1:5
    x = i
end
x # 5
```

A reference example: this time for loop fails to update the global.

```
x = 10
function foo(n)
  for i = 1:n
    x = i
  end
  1
end

foo(2), x # 1, 10
```

#### Update

The link from @matt-b is very useful. This is in fact the result of Soft Scope vs Hard Scope, [see here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/423#issuecomment-4116924). To wrap up, function scope used to work like loop scope, until there was a break change with the introduction of soft scope & hard scope. The documentation is not quite up to speed.

Comment: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/variables-and-scoping/

Comment: @Isaiah I have read the doc multiple times before posting. Still feel a bit strange about difference between function scope and loop scope, though the doc says they can both create new scope.

Comment: The differences you are seeing here are due to soft vs. hard scope.  See https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/9955 and the linked threads and PR for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link from @matt-b is very useful. This is in fact the result of Soft Scope vs Hard Scope, [see here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/423#issuecomment-4116924). To wrap up, function scope used to work like loop scope, until there was a break change with the introduction of soft scope & hard scope. The documentation is not quite up to speed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use global x in function scope you must declare it `global`

```
x = 10
function foo(n)
  global x
  for i = 1:n
    x = i
  end
  1
end

foo(2), x # 2
```

As @colinfang have commented, in Julia function scope and loop scope are treat differently and I think the following sentence from documentation try to address this fact:

> Julia uses lexical scoping, meaning that a function’s scope does not
>   inherit from its caller’s scope, but from the scope in which the
>   function was defined.

Comment: I know declare global explicitly would make it global. The thing I am unclear is that why function and loop are treated differently, though both of them may create new scope.

Comment: I'd say that this behavior makes much sense - in case of functions you rather want to change things by returning (unless they are mutable, like arrays and you do things like `x[i] = i` - your example would change the global scope in this case). With loops you do not have explicit input and output, and your intent is rather to modify variables defined in the outer scope.